# Abrir un excel temporal en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pyqt5, pyqt

He estado buscando cómo abrir un excel pero sólo he encontrado cómo abrir un excel ya creado:

```
os.system('start excel.exe "%s\\file.xls"' % (sys.path[0], ))
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es una ventana de "Desea abrir o guardar el excel?", pero para la opción de **abrir**, puesto que el excel no ha sido creado ni quiero que se guarde en ningún sitio no sé como indicárselo.

Estaba pensando en guardar el archivo y luego eliminarlo pero seguro que en `python` existe una opción para esto.

Lo que tengo hasta el momento es:

```
class modalExportacion(QWidget):
    ruta = ""
    fichero_actual = ""

    def __init__(self, df): 
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.df = df
        self.setWindowTitle("Exportacion a excel")

        contenedor = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(contenedor)

        label_3 = QLabel()
        label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        label_3.setText("Desea abrir o guardar el excel?")
        contenedor.addWidget(label_3, 1, 1)

        btnAbrir = QPushButton("Abrir",None)
        contenedor.addWidget(btnAbrir,2, 0)
        btnAbrir.clicked.connect(self.abrir)

        btnGuardar = QPushButton("Guardar",None)
        contenedor.addWidget(btnGuardar, 2, 1)
        btnGuardar.clicked.connect(self.guardar)

        btnSalir = QPushButton("Salir",None)
        contenedor.addWidget(btnSalir, 2, 2)
        btnSalir.clicked.connect(self.salir)


    def abrir(self):
        nombre_fichero = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Abrir fichero", self.ruta)
        if nombre_fichero:
            self.fichero_actual = nombre_fichero
            self.setWindowTitle(QFileInfo(nombre_fichero).fileName())
            self.ruta = QFileInfo(nombre_fichero).path()

            # TODO - Aqui va el codigo

    def guardar(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
    #     options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Guardar como...","","Excel (*.xls);;Todos los tipos (*)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            #escribimos los datos con pandas
            self.df.to_excel(fileName, index=False)

    def salir(self):
        exit()
```

Comment: Hola Adriana, no se si he captado lo que quieres ¿la idea es abrir MSExcel con el contenido del DataFrame pero sin crear un fichero en disco? Si es esto, vas a tener que crear si o si un archivo temporal manualmente o mediante [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tempfile.html). Si todo tubiera lugar en el proceso  Python podrias crear el archivo en memoria y trabajar con el normalmente, pero si lo va a usar excel.exe no es posible.

Comment: Si, me refería a eso. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes es usar la librería xlwings para abrir un nuevo excel, pero tendrías que automatizar el proceso, o sea, se abriría el excel y luego escribirías en el.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
sht.range('A1').value = lista_con_data
```

El código de arriba lo que hace es abrir MS Excel, y luego en la hoja "Sheet1" escribe datos iniciando desde la celda A1. El nombre de la hoja lo debes cambiar según si te lo muestra en español o ingles.

Puedes buscar más info acá: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html